# Cant turn on bluetooth

Tags: drivers

I can't turn on my Bluetooth. Anytime I go to Bluetooth under the system settings, I see Bluetooth turned off and I see `no bluetooth adapter found` but if I boot to bios, I do see the Bluetooth ID number.
My Bluetooth is an RTK
Also, unrelated possibly, but I am having an issue with my keyboard onboard brightness controller. The button works but its pretty slow before the changes take place.

I also can't turn on/off my WiFi from the onboard keyboard controller...The light just stays red. I can only turn it on/off from the WiFi icon at the top screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/616572/edit) the make/model of your Bluetooth device. And please give your question a nicer formatting ([markdown](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) supported).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you've all necessary drives installed, then try the command `rfkill unblock all` in terminal.

Comment: Its still the same not still working..you talked about driver.. Can u please tell me the driver to install maybe the one am using here is the one faulty

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i blue` say?

Comment: It gave me Bluetooth:core over 2.19 dem anoda Bluetooth: HCI device connection manageinitialized.Bluetooth: HCI socket layer intialized nd other details about the Bluetooth with a number right before each of the which is 19.872331

Comment: can you please tell me your bluetooth model by running `lspci`  in terminal?

Comment: Sorry please didn't get that...how do I add my Bluetooth model